# Manga where the main character finds a book which allows him to receive talents from previous famous people

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a manga where the main character finds a book, and he's able to use that book to receive talents from previous famous people. He even learns to use needles as a form of medicine as a talent to cure people.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, can you name any of the famous people who were referenced in the story?

Comment: Full color but it def couple years old. I cannot recall the names. 
I remember a specific scene in which he save a old woman using his needle technique to remove a tumor. 
I think the phrase oriental medicine was mentioned a lot

Comment: Do you recall any other skills that the MC used? Or any other notable characters? Also, what sort of world was the story set in? A modern city? The distant past? Were there any other magical/supernatural elements in the story?

Comment: Modern city. He also received a cooking skill from the book

Comment: I also think there are similar type of books in the story. I remember him defeating an old character. His book merged with the other characters into 1 book.

Comment: I believe he received fighting skill as well. Not sure what kind though

Answer (score 1):

Might be ***[I Stack Experience Through Reading Books](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/oxptkc3/read-to-level-up)***. Sounds the same; could be wrong though.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/read-to-level-up):

> Jongsuk is the pinnacle of mediocrity, with nothing to show for himself except his penchant for reading. One day, he finds a mysterious book at his favorite used book store. The book "tells" him to write about his experience in its blank pages, and in return shows him a related piece of information. Little did he know, the passages Jongsuk read in the books transferred right into his system, endowing with new abilities he never thought possible.

Edit: Not sure if they are all famous but he does receive all the powers talked about in the comments. While also coming across people with the same type of book, having to fight some. At this point I'm 100% sure this is the manga he's looking for unless there is a Manga with exactly the same plot and scenarios.

Comment: Does the main character receive talents from famous people in this? If so, could you edit your answer to provide some examples?